# Запись данных в PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, try, catch

Я записываю csv строки в базу данных PostgreSQL. В случае если данные отсутствуют, то обрабатывается исключение. Проблема заключается в том, что если обрабатывается блок except, то последующие данные не записываются, и выводится код с try и except. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
try:
    lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
    print(lines)
    query = ",".join(("%s" for _ in range(len(lines[0]))))
    query = f'INSERT INTO get_finance ("TICKER", "PER", "DATE", "TIME", "OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "CLOSE", "VOL") VALUES({query}) '
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(query, lines)
    connection.commit()
    time.sleep(1)
except:
    print(code + " данные отсутствуют")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Данные есть и записываются:

```
[['MSNG', '5', '11/10/21', '10:00:00', '2.3100000', '2.3200000', '2.3030000', '2.3120000', '773000']..

[['AGRO', '5', '11/10/21', '10:00:00', '1236.4000000', '1237.6000000', '1224.4000000', '1232.6000000', '16347']..
```

Данные отсутствуют(работает блок except):

```
ALNU данные отсутствуют
```

После исключения, данные не записываются и выводится код из try и except:

```
[['AMD-RM', '5', '11/10/21', '10:00:00', '7478.0000000', '7478.0000000', '7478.0000000', '7478.0000000', '2']

AMD-RM данные отсутствуют
```

Comment: Видимо, нужно всё же делать цикл по списку (снаружи от `try` и `except`) и использовать `execute` вместо `executemany`. Либо посмотрите, на каких значениях выходит ошибка и предварительно отфильтруйте из `lines` такие строки, которые дают ошибку.

Comment: `если обрабатывается блок except, то последующие данные не записываются,` это нужно подробней объяснить, имеенно - как вы после ошибки продолжаете? Второй вопрос, "данные отстуствуют" - это что значит? Пустой файл? Зачем в таком случае вообще делать запросы в БД? Поместите код работы с БД в `if lines: `. Если случилась ошибка при запросах к постгресу, то новые операции в этой транзакции делать нельзя, нужно начать новую транзакцию. Скорее всего у вас в этом проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена путем переноса `connection.commit()` за пределы блоков `try / except`:

```
try:
    lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
    query = ",".join(("%s" for _ in range(len(lines[0]))))
    query = f'INSERT INTO get_finance ("TICKER", "PER", "DATE", "TIME", "OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "CLOSE", "VOL") VALUES({query}) '
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(query, lines)
    print(lines)
    time.sleep(1)
except:
    print(code+" данные отсутствуют")
    time.sleep(1)
connection.commit()
```